# Django All SQL from syncdb

Tags: sql, django, django-syncdb

This may be a real stupid question. But how do you get ALL sql statements django-admin.py is going to run or does run from a syncdb command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use SQL for the command which will return all the SQL it will attempt to run

```
django-admin.py sqlall <App>
```

Comment: it's django-admin.py and not django_manage.py. and I would use 'sqlall <app>' instead of 'sql <app>'

Comment: And will output DDL, not DML. syncdb inserts data too.